# Dynamically preventing a gem in Gemfile from loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, rubygems, bundler

I have an unusual situation where I need to prevent a specific gem in `Gemfile` from loading based on the value of an environment variable.

Modifying `Gemfile` is not a good solution at this time because bundler is used in `--deployment` mode, which means that any changes to the Gemfile require a git commit, generation of `Gemfile.lock` by `bundle install --no-deployment` and then a re-issuance of `bundle install --deployment`.

I am not familiar with the Bundler codebase and I welcome ideas on how to achieve this without over-hacking/patching Bundler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there's not any way to accomplish this if you don't want to touch your `Gemfile`.

One solution would only require a one-time change to your `Gemfile`. You could add `require: false` to the line for the gem in question, making sure the gem's files don't get included by default:

```
gem 'gem_name', require: false
```

Then, you could add a file to `config/initializers` with something like this:

```
if ENV['MY_ENV_VARIABLE']
  require 'gem_name'
end
```

Depending on what the gem does this may or may not work, but it's a possible solution.